If $(X,\tau)$ is compact and $\mathcal{F}\subset C(X)$ is separating points, then the weak topology generated by $\mathcal{F}$ is equal to $\tau$

Let $\left(X,\tau\right)$ be a compact topological space, and let $\mathcal{F}\subset C(X)$ such that $\forall x\neq y\in X,\exists f\in\mathcal{F}:f(x)\neq f(y)$. Then the weak topology generated by $\mathcal{F}$ equals $\tau$.

So since $f\in\mathcal{F} \Rightarrow f\in C(X)$ we have that all $f\in \mathcal{F}$ are continuous relative to $\tau$, thus the weak topology generated by $\mathcal{F}$, which we'll denote by $\sigma$, satisfies $\sigma\subset\tau$. Now I want to show that given $U\in \tau$, one has that $U$ is a union of ($1$ or more) finite intersections of sets of the form $f^{-1}(V)$ where $V\subset\mathbb{R}$ is open. I can't figure out how to use the fact that $\mathcal{F}$ separates points or that $X$ is compact.

What can you say about continuous bijections from a compact space to a Hausdorff space?

@leoli1 I know it is a homeomorphism, but I'm unsure if this is what you suggested. I need to think about it furthermore, but as for now, I'm not sure how to find such a bijection in $\mathcal{F}$.

As $\sigma\subset \tau$, you know that the identity map $1_X\colon(X,\tau)\to (X,\sigma)$ is continuous.  Clearly it is a bijection.
You are given that $(X,\tau)$ is compact.
$(X,\sigma)$ is Hausdorff, as given $x\neq y\in X$, we have $f\in F$ with $f(x)\neq f(y)$, so we have disjoint neighbourhoods $U,V$ of $f(x), f(y)$ respectively, giving us $f^{-1}(U),f^{-1}(V)\in \sigma$ disjoint.
Thus $1_X$ is a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausorff space.  From comments, I think you know how to take it from there.
